# replace the substring of object in array?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In typescript, I have an object of array like variable1, I want to replace `name` substring of value from address key  to `new_name` and `address` to `new_address`. How can I do it?
I have something like

```
const variable2 = [
  variable1.map((object) => {
    object.address.replace('name', 'new_name');
    object.address.replace('address', 'new_address');
  }),
];
```

but I get error `TS2339: Property 'address' does not exist on type 'void[]'.`

```
export const variable1 = [
  {name: 'apple', address: `name=apple&address=apple_address}`, },
  {name: 'banana', address: `name=banana&address=banana_address}`, },
];
// vairable2
// export const variable1 = [
  // {name: 'apple', address: `new_name=apple&new_address=apple_address}`, },
  // {name: 'banana', address: `new_name=banana&new_address=banana_address}`, },] ;
```

Comment: Your code [compiles fine for me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwE4EsECMA2BTAjDAXhgG0AoGCmAbxjAQFtsAuGAcgQAcOdWAaGBABNBSbBAgtWdRgU7dsAMiEixEWVxwB9ZaPEBfVjD29ylGtOZt0COnT4DhuiWwsFrthEseq3Nv9u99Q2NSAF0AblJQSFhEVAwcACZCElM4tCw8ADp6TgAKPJB0ACtsYCgASkIAPmpTCiLS8qydVSzRbgRgbDypBmx7KWwAd00LVgrIyhhGsqgWwIh27E7u3tbxQbARgJVNydM9CpMIoA). Are you sure that's the definition of `variable1` you have in your actual code?

Comment: You aren't `return`ing anything from the `map`, so I'd assume that's the problem, but it's hard to say for sure without seeing more of the code.

Comment: it is my actual code, the only different is variable2. variable, name and address

Answer (score -1):

If all you want is replacing, you don't need map() method. You can use forEach(). This code will replace all items in your array.

```
variable1.forEach((object) => {
  object.address = object.address.replace('name', 'new_name')
                                 .replace('address', 'new_address');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are not reassigning the value to `object.address`, the `.replace()` doesn't override the actual string, it just returns the new value. that's what you want:

```js
const variable2 = [
    variable1.map((object) => {
        object.address = object.address.replace('name', 'new_name')
            .replace('address', 'new_address');
    }),
  ];
```